# Microsoft Graph - Planner and Teams APIs Return Failure (Status Code 403)

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I'm calling Microsoft Graph planner API and it returns 403 status code all the time.

This is the API URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{EMAIL}/planner/tasks that I'm calling.

I have updated all the required read and write permission in the Apps setting as **required**.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "You do not have the required permissions to access this item.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "90b22f0a-6d22-4770-93dc-bf7fa2d9bcbb",
        "date": "2019-05-20T10:58:07"
    }
  }
}
```

Also when I test from the Graph Explorer, I get the following response:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Your question lacks enough detail for the community here to help. Error messages without the code and payload that triggered them are rarely very informative.

Comment: Hi Marc! Sharing a payload is not the ideal thing as it might expose some critical information to the public. 
However, thanks for the valuable recommendation there is already someone below listed to me the missing required permissions and it is working now. So I guess my question is valid and obvious. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

To read planner tasks you need Tasks.Read permission for delegated access, and Tasks.Read.All permission for application access.

Outdated Reply:

> To be able to read Planner tasks, your app needs Groups.Read.All
> permission, which was missing in the request above.

Comment: Hi Tarkan, the permission "Groups.Read.All" is already granted to the app.

Comment: That particular request doesn't include Groups.ReadWrite.All. These were all the permissions granted for it: 
* Calendars.ReadWrite
* Contacts.ReadWrite
* Files.ReadWrite.All
* Mail.ReadWrite
* Notes.ReadWrite.All
* openid
* People.Read
* profile
* Sites.ReadWrite.All
* Tasks.ReadWrite
* User.ReadBasic.All
* User.ReadWrite
* email

Comment: Thank you,Tarkan! 

It is working now by adding the following permissions:
 * Calendars.ReadWrite * Contacts.ReadWrite * Files.ReadWrite.All * Mail.ReadWrite * Notes.ReadWrite.All * openid * People.Read * profile * Sites.ReadWrite.All * Tasks.ReadWrite * User.ReadBasic.All * User.ReadWrite * email